# Calling upon keys within a hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash, bioinformatics

This is something of an extension to [my very first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33049251) on this site.

Now I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Print Directory

print "Please provide the directory containing the FASTQ files from your Illumina MiSeq run \n";
my $FASTQ = <STDIN>;
chomp ($FASTQ);

print "Please provide the minimum overlap between the two reads in bp";
my $min = <STDIN>;
chomp ($min);

print "Please provide the maximum overlap between the two reads in bp";
my $max = <STDIN>;
chomp ($max);

print "Now provide the output directory for your merged fastq reads";
my $output = <STDIN>;
chomp ($output);

#Open Directory

my $dir = $FASTQ;
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Cannot open $dir: $!";
my @reads = grep { /.fastq/ } readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

sub parse_fastq_filename {
    # Strip the suffix
    my $filename = shift;

    # Parse Sample-ID_Adapter-Sequence_L001_R1_001
    my($sample_id, $adapter_sequence, $L001, $format, $001) = split /_/, $filename;

    return {
        filename            => $filename,
        sample_id           => $sample_id,
        adapter_sequence    => $adapter_sequence,
        $L001               => $L001,
        format              => $format,
        001                 => $001
    };
}


# The pairs of files will be stored within the following hash.
my %pairs;

# List just the *.fastq files
for my $filename (@reads) {
    # Parse the filename into a hash reference
    my $fastq = parse_fastq_filename($filename);

    # Put each parsed fastq filename into its pair
    $pairs{ $fastq->{sample_id} }{ $fastq->{format} } = $fastq;
}

for my $sample (values %pairs) {
    # Go through each pair in the sample
    for my $fastq (values %$sample) {
        print "$fastq->{filename} has format $fastq->{format}\n";
    }
}

for my $forward (values %pairs) {
    for my $fastq (values %$forward) {

    }
}

#print the keys within the hash
foreach (keys %pairs){
    print "$_ => $pairs{$_}\n";
}

#place the hash into an array
my @unique = keys %pairs;
print @unique;

#change directory to the user-inputted directory and merge reads 
chdir $dir;
`/usr/local/flash/flash @array[0] @array[1] -m $min -M $max -d $output`;
```

I successfully paired the forward and reverse fastq files with each other as required by the Unix command at the end. Now I'm stuck on how to call upon the individual components of the pairs with each other.

I've considered accessing the hash by typing in its keys as user input, but those numbers are randomly generated within the script, and I don't want to force the user to input those values before running the Unix script.

Plus, all the examples I've checked for have already provided a fixed amount of keys within the hash. Depending on how many files the user wants to merge together, the amount of keys within the hash can vary as well.

I know I want to make a loop so that the command can be run multiple times; the program FLASH can only accept one forward and reverse fastq file at a time. As such, the forward and reverse fastq reads must be looped so that each read will be processed.

How can I take out the specific file I want to work with after pairing them together into a hash?

Comment: Each question should stand on its own -- you really shouldn't rely on the contents of a previous question to fill in the detail for you. This question is really difficult to understand, but I *think* you want to extract the names of the two files corresponding to the two formats for each sample id. Is that right? Are the formats always `R1` and `R2`?

Comment: "Now I'm stuck on how to call upon the individual components of the pairs with each other." Could you clarify this requirement with an example to show what exactly you want to do?  "I've considered accessing the hash by typing in its keys as user input". I think this too needs some clarification. Sounds like you could use "keys %pairs" for this.

Comment: @Borodin Well for each pair there's a forward and a reverse read that's distinguished by the R1 and the R2 components respectively. So each file is formatted as sample-id_adapter-sequence_L001_R1/R2_001.fastq/

Ramana Well right now, I've got the script so that it parses the forward and reverse reads with each other. But they've been stuck into a single key within a hash. 

So if I had a key within the hash whose sample ID was "11215", then that key would have both the R1 and R2 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess at what you need is to pair up all the `.fastq` files in a given directory and call your `flash` utility once for each pair

There are a number of issues with your own code, and you seem to be retaining far more information thatn you need in your `%pairs` hash (I think all you need is the filename, the sample ID, and the format) so I've written this

I've also used a simple `glob` instead of `opendir` , `readdir`, `closedir` which seemed a better option

I've tested this as far as I can and it seems fine

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw/ basename /;

my $flash = '/usr/local/flash/flash';

print "Please provide the directory containing\n";
print "the fastq files from your Illumina MiSeq run: ";
my $fastq_file_dir = <STDIN>;
chomp $fastq_file_dir;

print "Please provide the minimum overlap between the two reads in bp: ";
my $min_overlap = <STDIN>;
chomp $min_overlap;

print "Please provide the maximum overlap between the two reads in bp: ";
my $max_overlap = <STDIN>;
chomp $max_overlap;

print "Now provide the output directory for your merged fastq reads: ";
my $out_dir = <STDIN>;
chomp $out_dir;

my @files = glob "$fastq_file_dir/*.fastq";

my %pairs;

for my $fastq_file ( @files ) {

    my $file = basename $fastq_file;
    my ($sample_id, $format) = (split /_/, $file)[0,3];

    $pairs{ $sample_id }{ $format } = $file;
}

printf "Processing %d pairs of FASTQ files\n\n", scalar keys %pairs;
chdir $fastq_file_dir;

for my $sample ( sort keys %pairs ) {

    my $pair = $pairs{$sample};
    my ($forward, $reverse) = @{$pair}{qw/ R1 R2 /};

    print "Forward: $forward\n";
    print "Reverse: $reverse\n";
    print "\n";

    my $cmd = qq{$flash $forward $reverse -m $min_overlap -M $max_overlap -d $out_dir};
    system $cmd;
}
```